# Yii2 pass value from text field to form model field

Tags: php, html, yii2

New to Yii2 and looking for some assistance, I have an address form that contains textinput boxes populated with address values and I would like to pass these values to ActiveForm on the same form. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 <form> <textarea id="address1"></textarea> pass value to <?= $form->field($model, 'address1')->textInput() ?> 

this is the form code;

<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<div>
<h1>Address Search</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="addressSearch">
    <input type="text" id="searchQuery">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchBtn">
    <div id="searchResult">
    </div>
      </div>
        <br>
      <form>
    <textarea id="address1"></textarea><br>
        <input type="text" id="town"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="postcode"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="locator_point">
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="address-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address1')->textarea() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'town')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'postcode')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'locator_point')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need the form twice?

Comment: textarea is populated from external source using javascript, I want to pass this data to the model. thanks

Comment: Why can't this javascript just populate the textarea in your `ActiveForm`?

Comment: Hi Alex, that would be a solution, can you advise how to. thanks

Comment: Without seeing the javascript I can't suggest how to change it.

Comment: had another look at what I'm trying to achieve, a better description would be that I want to  parse JSON post and save it to the database. thanks